# Special character's with LibGDX's I18NBundle such as "ü" or "ö" are marked as unknown

Tags: libgdx, localization

I am loading my `I18NBundle` like this :

```
    assetManager.load("i18n/language", I18NBundle.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();
    i18NBundle = assetManager.get("i18n/language", I18NBundle.class);
```

When I `get(String key)` the values of the german localization I get these symbols for the `ü` and `ö` characters. This is what it looks like when I use the debugger to see the mapped values :

[image]

In-game, it will display `Huser` instead of `Häuser`.

The french localization works fine with `é` and `è`. So I'm quite confused as why only the german localization fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Cedric's answer you should try these steps to make sore that the encoding is correct:

1. Make sure that the properties file uses the correct encoding. It might help to delete and re-create the file in some cases.
2. Make sure that the `I18NBundle` object uses the correct encoding. You do this by supplying the encoding when loading the bundle into the game:

   ```
   // Loading without asset manager
   I18NBundle.createBundle(baseFileHandle, encoding);

   // ex.
   I18NBundle.createBundle(Gdx.files.internal("game_en"), "UTF-8")

   // Loading with asset manager.
   I18NBundleParameter param = new I18NBundleParameter(locale, encoding);
   manager.load(fileName, I18NBundle.class, param);

   // ex.
   // null means it uses Locale.getDefualt()
   I18NBundleParameter param = new I18NBundleParameter(null, "UTF-8");
   manager.load("game_en", I18NBundle.class, param);
   ```

   Note that `UTF-8` is the default encoding for the `I18NBundle` and `Locale.getDefault()` is the default locale, so if you're going to use `UTF-8` you don't have to change the encoding and if you're going to use `Locale.getDefault()` you don't have to change the locale.
3. If none of this works **make sure your font supports your characters!** Too often have I made the mistake of using a font that doesn't include special characters just to notice this during the I18N process.

Answer (score 0):

Simply deleting my `language_de.properties` file and pasting the content back in worked. It may have been an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because language.properties file had been created in ANSI encoding and LibGDX uses UTF-8 by default, using notepad ++  I converted the file from ANSI to UFT-8